# Mathjax inline mode not rendering 

Tags: mathjax

In wordpress, I appended the [Mathjax CDN](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/platforms/wordpress.html) to my header file. The inline equations do not render while the display-mode equations seem fine. An example:

[image]

I have experience with Mathjax on another CMS (Drupal) and never had such a problem, or even on Math.SE . The reason I do not post it on the wordpress forum is because I did not install any plugin, so this has nothing to do with wordpress I guess.

Does anyone know why this is happening? For completeness, I appended the following script before the `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect this is 'off topic': it's really about WordPress rather than TeX.

Comment: @Joseph you may migrate it if you wish. I thought this was not related to wordpress, but mathjax, which belonged to "Tex Latex and friends". I may be wrong.

Comment: I will wait to see what others feel about this

Comment: I'm not sure where to recommend for this on SE; most likely the MathJaX mailing list.  MathJaX questions are on the border of what I would consider "on-topic".  This is about installing and/or configuring which I think is over that border.  I wouldn't expect someone who knows about TeX to even know where to start with this sort of thing, so although there might be someone here who could help, it's unlikely that this is the best place to ask to get the best chance of getting help.

Comment: @Andrew: I wondered about the WordPress SE site

Comment: @Joseph: I don't really know anything about that site.  They have 5 qns about MathJaX, and none are about installing it.  They do have a fair few about javascript in general, but this does feel like it is about configuring MathJaX rather than javascript in general, or installing something.  It would be worth a try, but I would say that the best place for the querrent to get help is the MathJaX mailing list.

Comment: Given your answer to Yannick's answer, I suspect that you should read the page on configuration options: http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/options/tex2jax.html

Comment: Have a careful look at the configuration, for inline it might be only the math delimitiers `\(...\)` are set, so try using these instead of `$...$`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can enable the `$ … $`-style inline mode by inserting the following code into the `<head>` section of your HTML *before* MathJax is being loaded. This way, you can invent new delimiters, too.

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
</script>
    
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Remember that after enabling this, you have to escape 'normal' dollar signs with `\$`.

A more detailed description can be found in the [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html). It also describes why the single dollar delimiters are disabled by default:

> Note that the single dollar signs are not enabled by default because they are used too frequently in normal text, so if you want to use them for math delimiters, you must specify them explicitly.

In MathJax v3, the configuration API changed. You now create a global MathJax object:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ["\\(", "\\)"]],
      processEscapes: true,
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Also, since the original posts some new issues come up. You may need to replace http:// with https:// everywhere you link to mathjax.

Comment: v3 syntax was necessary for me, otherwise, it won't work with the latest.

Answer (score 10):

Does it work if you use `\(` and `\)` ? At least for me, mathjax is pretty picky when it comes to formulas with just dollars around them.

Comment: Yes it does. My problem is that I have a habit of using `$ ... $` in my latex files, which I am trying to put up on my website.

Comment: if it's not working out for you try with \\( and \\)

Comment: This did the trick for me.